# how to get capture without storing it - Android

Tags: android, image, camera, storage, capture

I have the following code and I m trying to retrieve the image I captured without having to store it to the external storage before doing so. Is there a way to retrieve the image without storing it anywhere first?

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button captureBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    captureBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // get image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to retrieve the image without storing it anywhere first?

Take the picture with the camera yourself, using `android.hardware.Camera` or `android.hardware.camera2.*`.

Though in your code, since you do not have `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you should get a thumbnail back in the extras on the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`. A full-size photo will be much bigger than the 1MB IPC limit, which is why the third-party camera app cannot send you the full-size photo in RAM.